# Acrobat reader: "remove from recent" not shown for a signed document

Tags: acrobat, adobe-reader

If I click a document in Adobe Acrobat Reader "home tab", I see a list of actions on the right panel, including "Remove from recent".

However, if the document is a (securely) signed document, I see just a couple of options, not including "Remove from recent".

How to remove that document from the list?

A secondary solution (not that good):

- Menu > Preferences > Documents > "Documents in recently used list:" choose a low number and open so many other documents that the particular document falls out of the list